# Разделить список на равные части

Tags: python, python-3.x

В списке имеется 1000 элементов необходимо разделить их на 3 списка в ответе получит индексы срезов

```
def range_part(data, part):
    result = list()
    y = data
    data = data / part
    n = 0
    k = 0
    x = 1
    for i in range(1, part + 1):
        if x == part:
            result.append((n + 1, y))
        else:
            result.append((n + 1, k + int(data)))
            n = k + int(data)
            k += int(data)
            x += 1
    return result
```

Comment: А в чём проблема - делить не умеете? Уточните, что именно не получается

Comment: @MBo вопрос не в делении, а в получить функцию которая принимает число и вы водит срезы к примеру в данном случае [(1, 333), (334, 666), (667, 1000)], как то так

Comment: Ну так разделите 1000 на 3 и получите индексы. Вы же не первый день на SO - покажите свою функцию, скажите, что не работает  - тогда понятно, чем можно помочь

Comment: @MBo функция должна получить любое значение на вход и получить любое количество частей

Comment: @Дмитрий ну так *что конкретно у вас не получается*?

Comment: @strawdog уже получилось но код выглядит не очень, может как нибудь оптимизировать

Comment: data это что? part это что?

Comment: @Эникейщик, data- количество элементов, part - количество срезов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, конечно, не совсем индексы срезов, но те же значения, которые вы хотели

```
def range_part(size, nparts):
    result = list()
    for i in range(nparts - 1):
        result.append((size//nparts*i + 1, size//nparts*(i+1)))
    result.append((size//nparts*(nparts-1) + 1, size))
    return result
```